# while loop, does not check the condition

Tags: java

```
String quit="N";
        int i=0;
        ArrayList<String> course = new ArrayList<String> ();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (quit!="y")
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Course code or y to exit:");
            quit=scan.next();
            System.out.println(quit);
        };
        System.out.println("out");
  }
```

Im trying to quit the loop if the input is "y", but however the while loop continues execution over and over even after the input is "y", please help.

Answer (score 1):

use `String.equals` to compare two strings.